# Paint every point of the plane with either blue or red color. Show that there are 2 points on the plane (same color) one inch apart.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, pigeonhole-principle

I need help with this question, because I do not understand some points.

**Pigeonhole Question:** Paint every point of the plane with either blue or red color. Show that there are 2 points on the plane (same color) one inch apart.

**Hint I have received:** Imagine an equilateral triangle with sides of 1 inches.

**Problem with the hint:** Why an equilateral triangle? Where does the triangle come in?

**My Proof Attempted With the Hint:**

If there is an equilateral triangle with sides of 1 inch apart, and two of the vertices were different colors. The third vertical point must be one of the two colors, therefore proving that there are two points, same color, one inch apart.

Comment: In an equilateral triangle, the distance between any two vertices is the same. If you took a right-angled triangle with side lengths $1,1,\sqrt{2}$, the argument wouldn't go through.

Comment: But where does the triangle even come in? Was the triangle just taken from a random part of the plane?

Comment: You have two holes (the colours). You need (at least) three pigeons (points) to apply the pigeonhole principle. Any three points in the plane are the vertices of a (possibly degenerate) triangle. To make the triangle relevant for the desired conclusion, the distance between any two of its vertices must be one inch. And that makes it an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @AyT The use of the pigeonhole principle is that if you have more objects than bins, then you must have some bin with more than one object. You have two colours in the plane, so you need 3 or more points to force your collection of points to have more than one of the same colour. It didn't have to be an equilateral triangle, but it's the regular polygon with the smallest number of vertices which will work.

Comment: Quite a bit harder, until you see the trick: If we paint the points of the plane using **three** colours, there are $2$ points one inch apart that have the same colour.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is essentially how to **derive** the solution (including the hint). In general there is no deterministic way (and there cannot be), but often we try to prove stronger claims if we believe the result is true and weaker than necessary.

The original statement is:

> Given any 2-colouring of the points in the plane, there are two points of the same colour with distance 1.

The stronger statement is:

> There is a finite set $S$ of points in the plane, such that given any 2-colouring of $S$, there are two points of the same colour with distance 1.

Why do we think this is true, in this problem?

To solve any problem one has to first **experiment**. If one doesn't even try special cases, one can forget about solving any significant problem at all. In this problem, we could start with simple 2-colourings of the plane (say the left half red and the right half blue), but we also should try colouring **one point at a time**. This latter approach leads to the solution directly:

> Start with some arbitrary point $P$. Since we haven't coloured anything yet, we can colour this one red (blue's the same).
>
> Now a lot of points can't be coloured red anymore, in fact a whole circle of them of radius 1 centred at $P$ must be coloured blue.
>
> Wait a minute now there are obviously two points on that circle coloured blue!

The solution is complete, but if you look closer you see that it didn't really look at all the points on the circle; it only needed to look at 2 of them that form an equilateral triangle with $P$.

So the moral of the story is that the hint was crafted by someone who knew the solution and didn't really know how to motivate **finding** the solution by oneself...